# Hardcoded user/pass work for MySQL connection, but strings from file do not

Tags: php, mysql

First off, I'm trying to make sure that I'm not showing my MySQL password in my index page's source code.  I've determined that making a "mysql.conf" file with the information I need will be sufficient.

Here is the section of code, pre-conf file.  This worked without any problems:

```
$dbhost = "mysql.host.com";
$dbuser = "username";
$dbpass = "password";
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

Now, here is the configuration file's contents (mysql.conf):

```
mysql.host.com
username
password
```

And the corresponding changes to the code...

```
$dbConfig = file("./config/mysql.conf");
$dbhost = $dbConfig[0];
$dbuser = $dbConfig[1];
$dbpass = $dbConfig[2];
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

However, with the changes to use the configuration file, the MySQL connection now fails, giving me this error response:

"Could not connect: Access denied for user 'username'@'chain-lightning.dreamhost.com' (using password: YES)"

What am I missing?  I've triple-checked that the text in the configuration file is the same as when I used static strings.  Thanks!

Comment: first of all, php code will not render in page source code

Comment: and if you want to define constant you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php link to define constants

Comment: mysql_ is deprecated kindly use mysqli_ or PDO

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting mostly because of the data getting from file is not as you think. all your value will be added with extra newline value.

from http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

> Returns the file in an array. Each element of the array corresponds to
>   a line in the file, with the newline still attached.

use trim function with your variable it will work fine.

```
$dbConfig = file("./config/mysql.conf");
$dbhost = trim($dbConfig[0]);
$dbuser = trim($dbConfig[1]);
$dbpass = trim($dbConfig[2]);

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

or you can use **FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES** flag in file function

```
$dbConfig = file("./config/mysql.conf", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$dbhost = $dbConfig[0];
$dbuser = $dbConfig[1];
$dbpass = $dbConfig[2];

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

Comment: Good point!  I will give this a try when I get back home.  I resorted to using a config.php file and defining my variables, which works as well.  If this solved the problem, I will accept this answer.

Thank you for the response!